# MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver UTF-8 encoding

Tags: mysql, utf-8, odbc

Currently I am migrating MSSQL to MySQL. I am using the MySQL ODBC 3.51 driver to connect to MySQL using ODBC connectivity. I have Telugu language characters stored in the table. They are not showing properly while using the MySQL ODBC driver, but they are showing up properly while using the sqlserver ODBC driver.

My connection string is

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=dbtest; User=user1;Password=mysql;Option=3;CharSet=utf8;
```

Please suggest a solution to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.mysqltalk.org/unicode-utf-8-question-vt188135.html) you can make it work by setting the DNS's 'Connect Options'->'Initial Statement' to 'SET NAMES utf8'.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue. In addition to answer above, I was also able to get the data to transfer properly by changing the character set in the column of my database to either ASCII or Latin1. I believe ODBC will not convert encoding which can result in mismatches with the database.