# KonaKart. Wrong character in database

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, konakart

I installed Konakart successfully. I am using MySQL database and set utf-8 encoding. 
In addition I add russian language, but when I create new user and specify name with russian character in the database displayed onlly ??? signs. If I point to the database manually, everything is displayed correctly.

UPDATE

character from database displayed correctly, but some problems encoding occurred with file properties Messages.properties

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues. First thing to do is find out what exactly has been written to the database. This is very easy with MySQL, just logon and run

```
SELECT HEX( column ) FROM table;
```

Though from what you're saying, the correct bytes are in the database already. Next thing is to check what character set your connection from Konakart is set to. After you've connected, run "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'" and print out the results. If nothing else it's a useful check to see if the character set options you've specified have taken.

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869778/fetching-utf-8-text-from-mysql-in-r-returns/12872139#12872139) might be useful.

Comment: thanks, character from database displayed correctly, but some problems encoding occurred with file properties Messages.properties

Answer (score 0):

Properties files should be saved as ISO-8859-1 files

You can add your special characters using a \uXXXX format or create a UTF-8 version of the Properties file and use native2ascii to convert it.

eg:

native2ascii -encoding utf8 myProps.utf8 myProps.properties