# UTF8 encoding using RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, utf-8, rmysql

I am trying to query data from a mysql database, which contains some strings, of course. For the connection and data retrieval I am using RMySQL in R, which works fine. Apart from one thing: the strings I am retrieving seem not to be in utf8. But I need this, because I have some german "Umlaute" in these strings.
When I ask teh databse, which are its encoding by

```
dbGetQuery(db, "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';")
```

I get the desired answer:

```
             Variable_name           Value
1   character_set_client             utf8
2   character_set_connection         utf8
3   character_set_database           utf8
4   character_set_filesystem         binary
5    character_set_results           utf8
6     character_set_server           utf8
7     character_set_system           utf8
8       character_sets_dir C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\share\\charsets\\
```

But e.g. I receive

```
Andreas WÃ¼nsche
```

instead of

```
Andreas Wünsche
```

Hope that somebody knows how to deal with it. If additonal information is needed, just ask. I can provide it.

Comment: Have you tried to change the default encoding of R ? If you are using R studio go : Tool -> Global Options -> Code -> Saving and put UTF-8

Comment: yes, it is already set to utf8 in Rstudio

Comment: Ok. I have tried to use some iconv function to set the WÃ¼nsche to the proper format but didn't find any solution... i will continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find something a bit tricky but works for me :

you have to manually define the col of your data frame to utf-8 like this :

```
x <- "WÃ¼nsche"
Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"
x
[1] "Wünsche"
```

Think you have to do this to all your strings vector

### EDIT :

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634734/displaying-japanese-characters-retrieved-from-mysql-in-r)
seems to fix the same problem by adding `'set character set "utf8"'`inside the `dbSendQuery()`

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But I would like to know, how this happens, that the encoding is set to "unkown".

Comment: may be the SQL query dont apply the format to the R object

Comment: The character set approach did not work for me. I have to keep your encoding workaround. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2):

I took this answer from: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-db/2012q1/001141.html
Before `dbSendQuery` you have to place `dbGetQuery(mydb, "SET NAMES 'utf8'")`

```
mydb <-  dbConnect(MySQL(), user = db_user, password = db_password,
               dbname = db_name, host = db_host, port = db_port)

s=dbGetQuery(mydb, "SET NAMES 'utf8'") 
s=paste0("select * from ", db_table) 
rs=dbSendQuery(mydb, s)
df=fetch(rs, n = -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Mojibake**, check the following.
This discussion also applies to **Double Encoding**, which is not necessarily visible.

- The bytes to be stored need to be utf8-encoded.
- The connection when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing` text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4.
- The column needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).
- HTML should start with `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.