# special characters encoding between Windows and Linux shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that retrieves values from a db and prompt them in different forms (selectizeInput, datatable etc...).
My R files are all encoded in UTF8. My tables in my database are for some in latin1 and for others in UTF8 encoded. (I am slowly switching from latin1 to UTF8!)

When I prompt my app using R Studio on windows, I have the special characters from my database printed correctly (déjeuner for instance). No matter the table (UTF8 or latin1)

However, when I push it on my shiny server (linux), I loose the special characters (déjeuner becomes djeuner) no matter the table
. 
Would some of you have an idea or have already encountered this issue?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: You can find the solution to this question on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634734/displaying-japanese-characters-retrieved-from-mysql-in-r.

Comment: Perfect Romain it works fine with this solution! great! Just need to figure out why my db and app is behaving like that...