# source()ing a file changes the BOM characters in a function

Tags: r, byte-order-mark, rmysql

I have a `.R` file that contains several functions, one of which is defined as:

```
get_entry_detail <- function(con, vec_of_entryids){

  query <- paste0("select entryId, fieldName, fieldValue
                         from `hthu-eligibility`.entry_detail
                  where entryId in (", paste(vec_of_entryids, collapse = ","), ");")

  dbGetQuery(con, query) %>%
    mutate(fieldName = ifelse(fieldName == "ï»¿firstName",
                              gsub(paste(c("ï»¿"), collapse = "|"), "", fieldName),
                              fieldName))

}
```

Note that there is a `mutate()` that strips off a `ï»¿` when `fieldName == "ï»¿firstName"`.

I `source()` this file at the top of another `.R` file but when I view the function after sourcing the file, the function has changed to:

```
> source("R/get_join_employee_data_userid.R")
> get_entry_detail
function(con, vec_of_entryids){

  query <- paste0("select entryId, fieldName, fieldValue
                         from `hthu-eligibility`.entry_detail
                  where entryId in (", paste(vec_of_entryids, collapse = ","), ");")

  dbGetQuery(con, query) %>%
    mutate(fieldName = ifelse(fieldName == "Ã¯Â»Â¿firstName",
                              gsub(paste(c("Ã¯Â»Â¿"), collapse = "|"), "", fieldName),
                              fieldName))

}
```

And the `ï»¿` has now changed to `Ã¯Â»Â¿`. This causes later functions to fail because there is no `ï»¿` that needs to be removed thus later joins fail.

How do I prevent this from happening? I can't adjust the database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding of files is OS dependent. On my Linux machine your example runs without problems. Linux uses `UTF-8` as default encoding. However, Windows uses the system's default encoding which may differ from `UTF-8`.

Hence, explicitly specifying `encoding="UTF-8"` in `source()` should fix the problem:

```
source("R/get_join_employee_data_userid.R", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29001713/4351030) provided a solution. Now my function look like:

```
get_entry_detail <- function(con, vec_of_entryids){

  dbSendQuery(con, 'set character set "utf8"')

  query <- paste0("select entryId, fieldName, fieldValue
                         from `hthu-eligibility`.entry_detail
                  where entryId in (", paste(vec_of_entryids, collapse = ","), ");")

  dbGetQuery(con, query)
}
```

although I still don't know why the characters were changed when I sourced the file rather than reading it in directly.

Comment: It looks like your script is encoded in UTF-8 and `source` reads it as if it was encoded in windows-1252. If I'm right then you just need to use the `encoding` argument: `source("R/get_join_employee_data_userid.R", encoding = "UTF-8")`.