# Character encoding in R MySQL on Linux machine

Tags: sql, r, ubuntu, encoding, rmysql

I'm trying to fetch data which includes some German word with umlaut characters. following the bellow structure everything is fine in windows machine :

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')

library(RMySQL)
  conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "user", dbname = "database", 
                    host = "host", password = "pass")
sql.query <- paste0("some query")

df <- dbSendQuery(conn, sql.query)
  names <- fetch(df, -1)
  dbDisconnect(conn)
```

As an example I have :

```
names[1230]
[1] "Strübbel"
```

What should I change in order to get the same result in Linux Ubuntu ?
the query will run without problem, but the result is :

```
names[1230]
[1] "Str\374bbel"
```

I have checked [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634734/displaying-japanese-characters-retrieved-from-mysql-in-r) solution, but when I put the `'set character set "utf8"'` inside of query I'm getting the following error :

```
df <- dbSendQuery(conn, sql.query, 'set character set "utf8"')
names <- fetch(df, -1)
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  unused argument ("set character set \"utf8\"")
```

I should mention the encoding for the result is unknown :

```
Encoding(names[1230])
[1] "unknown"
```

and doing the :

```
Encoding(names[1230]) <- "UTF-8"

names[1230]
[1] "Str<fc>bbel"
```

does not solve the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

`Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')`

You have to use :

`Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','en_US.UTF-8')`

and in the sql query :

```
library(RMySQL)
  conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "user", dbname = "database", 
                    host = "host", password = "pass")
sql.query <- paste0("some query")

dbSendQuery(conn,'set character set "utf8"')
df <- dbSendQuery(conn, sql.query)
  names <- fetch(df, -1)
  dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this solution will help you but you could try such approach:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "user", dbname = "database", 
                    host = "host", password = "pass", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

If this encoding doesn't work then try "brute force" with different variants