# Reading in special characters from SQL into R

Tags: mysql, sql-server, r, utf-8

I'm running R connecting via RODBC.
    No matter what I try, the query result shows ????? for Greece characters.

```
library(RODBC)
imp <- odbcConnect("DTM_SQL_SERVER", uid = "*********", pwd="******",DBMSencoding="utf8")
msg_recus<-sqlQuery(imp,"select * from mabase;")
libelle : avene-????se t? ?????! - 2015_10_28
```

original text i would like:
AVENE-Νίκησε το Χρόνο! - 2015_10_28

Thanks for your answer

Comment: The encoding won't be UTF8 then. But without access to the database it's impossible to figure out which one it is exactly. If you're on a Windows system, try DBMSencoding = 'latin1'. If that doesn't do it, you'll have to look up which actual encoding is used in the database.

Comment: DBMSencoding = 'latin1' : doesn't work so in the database the column's type is nvarchar(128)

Comment: doesn't work means you get an error or you get the exact same result?

Comment: I get the exact same result

Comment: Try the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869778/fetching-utf-8-text-from-mysql-in-r-returns

Comment: I already try but I don't know how to do it : For RODBC, connect using CharSet=utf8 in the DSN string

Comment: And  in the end i don't use mysql . I just have R and SQL server 2008 where i can see: AVENE-Νίκησε το Χρόνο! - 2015_10_28 but I just can't seem to get this in R

Answer (score 0):

Multiple question marks usually derives from

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

Are you sure the `DBMSencoding="utf8"` is right for connecting to MySQL?  (That *should* cover for `SET NAMES utf8`.)

Comment: I tried something: i have used the basic function read.csv2 to read my label in R. I have the exactly same label : avene-?????? ?? ?????! - 2015_10_28

Comment: The question marks you are reading is what is in the table -- the orignal characters are lost.  Have you change the table declaration?  Have you re-inserted the data?

Comment: I 've just tried to see if the problem is reproducible. But in SQL server 2008 my real original data i can see : AVENE-Νίκησε το Χρόνο! - 2015_10_28

Comment: The question marks usually are cause by mis-configuration during the `INSERT`.

Comment: I dont have any insert anywhere. I just connect to my base with odbcConnect and extract some data from a table