# R utf-8 (persian) importing from mysql

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc

I am totally new to R programming.I've got a database in MySQL and a column of this database include data in UTF-8 charset(Persian).
I did import the table from the database into the R studio with (RODBC), but the resulting character is not correct:
[image: a damaged part of retrieved data]

I did unique body col. and then changed its encoding, and it worked.
      `temp <- unique(postT$body)`,
     `temp2<- as.character(temp)`,
      `Encoding(temp2) <- "UTF-8"`
but it cannot be a permanent solution. Since, then I cannot have any access to the whole dataset.
Also, I'd checked my ODBC connection setting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869778/fetching-utf-8-text-from-mysql-in-r-returns?answertab=votes#tab-top) and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Why can't you just set `Encoding(postT$body) = 'UTF-8'`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico this is what happened to it!! one of the table body col. entries: `<U+062F><U+0648><U+0631><U+0647> <U+0622>...`