# R database table pull encoding issue

Tags: r, encoding, dbplyr

I have a MySQL database containing a table of names. Once I pull them into R I run into some encoding problems which I don't understand but seem to be all related to the way R interpreted the file.

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 host = 'localhost',
                 user = 'root',
                 dbname='test',
                 rstudioapi::askForPassword('Database password')
)
```

and pull the `names` table from my MySQL db with

```
df <- dbReadTable(con, 'names')
```

My table looks something like

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(373863, 17731249), name = c("AARESTRUP, JAN CAROÌ¸E", 
"BÃœTTNER, CHRISTIAN")), .Names = c("id", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))


df
        id                   name
1   373863 AARESTRUP, JAN CAROÌ¸E
2 17731249    BÃœTTNER, CHRISTIAN
```

Checking the encoding brings

```
Encoding(df$name)
[1] "unknown" "unknown"
```

Using `Encoding(df$name) <- "UTF-8"` fixes the second name but turns parts of name one into a non UTF-8 character.

```
df
        id                         name
1   373863 AARESTRUP, JAN CARO<U+0338>E
2 17731249           BÜTTNER, CHRISTIAN
```

Now it gets strange as `df$name[1]` returns
`[1] "AARESTRUP, JAN CARO̸E"` which is exactly how it is stored in the MySQL db while it seems like its differently interpreted when I call the whole `df`.

First, is there a way to ensure the `dbReadTable()` reads in automatically `UTF-8`. I found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869778/fetching-utf-8-text-from-mysql-in-r-returns) which does not seem to change anything in terms of my table encoding.

Second, what is going on with the difference in the interpretation of the non UTF-8 encoding depending on how you access the name (whole df vs. single element)

Answer (score 1):

`<U+0338>` is a [UTF-8 character](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/U00338.html). But it's an overlay character that when rendered occupies the same space as the O that preceeds it. For some reason, it's displaying it incorrectly (although I checked and in R it displays correctly, so it seems to be something to do with StackOverflow, or perhaps Firefox). You can use

```
apply(df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) if( typeof(x) == 'character' ) Encoding(x)<-'UTF-8')
```

on all of your database result tables, which will convert encoding to UTF-8 for all of the character columns.

I think that the difference in behavior between when you call `df$name[1]` and when you call `df` has to do with the different print/show methods for character type objects vs data.frames.

`df` wants to show you the individual characters, meaning it doesn't want to render the characters in a way that disguises the fact that the E with a slash is in fact two characters. It also doesn't want to display the character as a spacing character, since it would then look like a backslash. Showing the unicode for the character is the best way to let the user know it is there.

The show method for character type objects wants to render the characters for you (most of the time).